# Parallax effect works fine in Firefox & Chrome, but 'misbehaves' in IE 11?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, parallax

http://clayvos.com/portfolio/weatoc/

Check out my above link to a demo bootstrap website I am working on.  The landing page works fine in Firefox & Chrome but the shaded area on the first page doesn't scroll right in IE 11?  Has anyone else run into a problem like this before?  Any work around's and/or fixes?

Comment: what is not working? I tested it with msie11 and everything seems to be working. Maybe on msie the effect is a little bit laggy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch the DOM as you scroll and you'll see the problem. A new HTML node is creating during each scroll event:

```
<div class="fit-vids-style">...</div>
```

IE is applying height to that for some reason (I didn't really look too deep).

You're problem is in this block at the very bottom:

```
<script>
    var navbar = jQuery('#navbartop');
    var topnavbar = jQuery('#topnavbar');
    var logoGlobeChange = jQuery('.logoColorGlobeChange');
    var logoTextChange = jQuery('.logoColorTextChange');
    var hero = jQuery('#header-section .hero-unit');
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 640) {
            navbar.addClass("navbar-scroll");
            topnavbar.addClass("cbp-af-header-shrink");
            topnavbar.removeClass("navbar-static-top");
            topnavbar.addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
            logoGlobeChange.removeClass("whiteLogo");
            logoGlobeChange.addClass("logoColorGlobe");
            logoTextChange.addClass("logoColorText");
            hero.addClass("hide");
            $('.navbar .nav .dropdown-toggle .caret').css({ "margin-top": "22px"});
            $('.navbar .nav li.dropdown > .dropdown-toggle .caret ').css({"border-top-color": "#777777"});
            $('.navbar .nav li.dropdown > .dropdown-toggle .caret ').css({"border-bottom-color": "#777777"});
            $('.customizedModal ').css({"padding-top": "15px"});
            $('.customizedModal').css({"padding-bottom": "15px"});
            $('.navbar .nav li.dropdown > a:hover .caret, .navbar .nav li.dropdown > a:focus .caret').css({"border-top-color": "#777777"});

        } else {
            navbar.removeClass("navbar-scroll");
            topnavbar.removeClass("cbp-af-header-shrink");
            topnavbar.removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
            topnavbar.addClass("navbar-static-top");
            logoGlobeChange.removeClass("logoColorGlobe");
            logoTextChange.removeClass("logoColorText");
            logoGlobeChange.addClass("whiteLogo");
            hero.removeClass("hide");
            $('.navbar .nav .dropdown-toggle .caret').css({ "margin-top": "35px"});
            $('.navbar .nav li.dropdown > .dropdown-toggle .caret ').css({"border-top-color": "#ffffff"});
            $('.navbar .nav li.dropdown > .dropdown-toggle .caret ').css({"border-bottom-color": "#ffffff"});
            $('.navbar .nav li.dropdown > a:hover .caret, .navbar .nav li.dropdown > a:focus .caret').css({"border-top-color": "#ffffff"});
            $('.customizedModal').css({"padding-top": "10px"});
            $('.customizedModal').css({"padding-bottom": "10px"});
        }

        // Basic FitVids Test
        $(".container").fitVids();
    });
</script>
```

You need to move the `$(".container").fitVids();` to outside of the scroll function.

```
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 640) {
            //...
        } else {
            //...
        }
    });


    // Basic FitVids Test
    $(".container").fitVids();
```

Unless you need that triggered on scroll. If so, you'll need to set some boolean flag to do it only once.

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick:)